# Passing objects to procedures in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a simple tool that will allow me to parse multiple CSV files and spit them out onto a fresh worksheet "merged" together.  Here is my implementation (I've simplified it) and my issue:

Class A

```
private variables as types
property methods for accessing variables
```

Class B

```
private variables as types
property methods for accessing variables
```

Class C

```
Private cA as ClassA
Private cB as Collection  'Collection of ClassB
```

Class D - Part of my problem

```
Private cC as Collection 'Collection of ClassC
'Other member variables and their property get/lets

Public Sub AddA(A as ClassA)
    If cC.Item(A.foo) is Nothing then 
        dim tempC as ClassC
        set tempC = new ClassC
        tempC.A = A
    End if
End Sub
```

Main Module - Other half of my problem

```
Dim cC as New ClassC
'Initialize Class C, this all works fine
Dim tempA as ClassA
Set tempA = new ClassA
'Set tempA properties
cC.AddA tempA  'This is where my error is
```

I've tried passing it as `ByVal` and `ByRef` each gives me different errors ("byref argument type mismatch", "invalid procedure or argument", and "Object doesn't support this property or method"

I have no idea what to try next, I even tried the parenthesis "thing" that supposedly forces the parameter into either ByVal or ByRef, I can't remember, that was yesterday.

Thanks.

Comment: The error is inside `AddA`, so some code would help. I'd also bet you want `Public Sub AddA(ByVal A as ClassA)`.

Comment: @GSerg I receive the error in the main module calling the sub, and I've tried using `ByVal A as ClassA`, I get the "Invalid procedure or argument" error.  Please note I added the code for AddA, and realised at the same time I completely left out a class.  I've completely updated all the code.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Play with `Tools -> Options -> General -> Error Trapping` to change where you see the error. In this case you might want "Break in class module."

Comment: @GSerg Ok, now I see where the error is actually occurring, and it seems to be where I preform my check `If cC.Item(A.Foo) is Nothing then`, according to the docs if the item doesn't exist, it will simply error instead of returning a nothing value.  Let me fix this, then we'll see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
tempC.A = A
```

means "assing to `A` property of `tempC` object the value of the default property of the `A` object."
Your `A` object apparently doesn't have a default property.

What you actually meant was probably:

```
Set tempC.A = A
```

But even then, you can't access a private field `A` of `C` class from `D` class. Make the field public or create a public `SetA()` method on `C` class and call it from `D`.

Comment: This didn't actually solve my problem, it was actually somewhere else in my code, but you set me looking on the right path, and I didn't know about the Error Trapping settings (which helped a ton), so I'm going to mark this as the answer.