# Recordset .value property

Tags: vb6

Please see the DDL below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TestDate (bookingdate datetime)
INSERT INTO TestDate VALUES ('2013-10-04')
```

Please see the ADODB recordset below:

```vb
rs.open "SELECT bookingdate FROM TestDate"
If rs("bookingdate") > dateadd("yyyy", -6, Now)
  msgbox("test")
end if
```

What is the difference between specifying `rs("bookingdate")` and `rs("bookingdate").value`.  I have read some questions on here where answerers say always use .value, but it is not explained why.  I had a look on MSDN but could not find an answer.

Comment: The "why" is the same risk factor involved in any use of a default property.  People will blithely ignore this and get away with it 99 times out of 100 and then that 100th time get bitten HARD by a very hard to diagnose bug.

Answer (score 2):

`Value` is the [default property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18051644/11683) of the `Field` object, so in VB6 there is no difference between `rs("bookingdate")` and `rs("bookingdate").value` [when used without `Set`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17877644/11683).

I personally prefer not using default properties that don't take parameters. It makes the code [less confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5966716/11683) IMO.

In VB.NET the default property must have a parameter, so this situation does not occur.
Note `Recordset` has such default property with parameter, and you are using it to return the `Field` object: `rs("bookingdate")` is actually `rs.Item("bookingdate")`. Using those, IMO, makes no harm.

Comment: SET involves manipulating the reference according to your link.  Is that correct?

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, it involves manipulating the reference. E.g. you could declare a variable `f` of type `Field` and `Set f = rs("bookingdate")`.

Comment: Not true.  There are many cases where `Set` isn't a factor, such as any time you pass the expression as an argument to some procedure.

Comment: @Bob77 While passing parameters is a different matter that has little to do with assigning variables, it also may or may not use default properties (which also adds confusion). If you take expression `rs("bookingdate")` and pass it to a procedure that accepts a `Field`, `Object` or `Variant` parameter, the `Field` object will be passed. If you pass same expression to a procedure that accepts e.g. a `String` parameter, the compiler will call `rs("bookingdate").Value` and pass that.

Comment: It seems like everyone wants to contrive examples to prove that lazy reliance on default properties is a healthy thing.  It *isn't* and has never been a recommended practice.  It makes it harder for anyone (including the compiler) to know what's intended.  However... you always have the option to do so, it just isn't considered good practice.

Comment: @Bob77 Who is doing that? [I'm not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19200523/11683). The people the OP met [aren't doing it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19200428/11683) either.