# Operator Overloading in VBA

Tags: vba

I have noticed that, when I create a custom collection class (as explained in [this blog](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/07/04/custom-collection-class/))
, the operator "()" becomes automatically available  so that it is a synonym to the `Item` method.

Are there other forms of operator overloading, implicit or otherwise, available in VBA? And where are those behaviors documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not operator overloading, this is marking a property as the default property of an object.

This is a COM feature, and it is merely supported by VB.

When an object that has a default property is used in a non-reference context (without `Set`), the value of the default property will be automatically used instead of the object pointer.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200523/11683) for more information (also follow the other links from there).

Comment: FYI - To implement a default property you have to export the .cls file, edit it with Notepad and re-import it in your project.

Comment: @ja72 Yes, this is what is suggested in the article linked by the OP.