# Worksheets vs. Worksheets(1), can't I do this from .net interop?

Tags: excel, com-interop, vba

Our object model contains a class called Unit and a collection of these called Units (which is stored in a Dictionary). These objects have unique Names and Keys (they originally came from a SQL db that enforced this) so I have added:

```
Public Units(N as String) As Unit ...
Public Units(K as Integer) As Unit...
```

which return a Unit object from the Units collection.

In Excel VBA, one can refer to most objects using similar methods; `Worksheets(1)` returns the first sheet, while `Worksheets("Bob")` returns the named sheet. But they have one additional method, `Worksheets`, which returns the entire collection. It's as if they have this method...

```
Public Worksheets() As List(Of Worksheet)
```

But you can't use List in interop (**right?**) so it's more like...

```
Public Worksheets() As ArrayList
```

So how would I do the same basic API in .net with interop? That is, have three methods...

```
Public Units(N as String) As Unit ...
Public Units(K as Integer) As Unit...
Public Units() As ArrayList...
```

As I understand it only the first method of a given name is exported (**is this correct?**). So how does Excel do it, and can I fake that in .net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA's `Worksheets` is not a method. It is a class, `Worksheets`, that has a [default property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20738851/11683) `Item` that accepts a parameter of type `Variant`. There is no overloading (COM does not support it), it's just that `Variant` can hold both a number or a string.

If you want a similar structure in VB.NET, you can have a collection class that implements a [default property as VB.NET understands it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az06zx4y(v=vs.90).aspx), and this time you can overload it.

```
Public Class UnitsCollection

    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal i As Integer) As Unit
        Get
            Return ...
        End Get
    End Property

    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal i As String) As Unit
        Get
            Return ...
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Ok, so if I'm parsing this correctly, a call to `Worksheets("Bob")` is really a call to `Worksheets.Item("Bob")`, and additionally, the method `Item` takes a variant, figures out what was passed in, and then does the lookup based on that. Right?  Ok, so what does the straight-up `Worksheets` call? Is this calling a method on the class? Is it a collection on some other object like, I don't know, `Workbook`? When I say `Workbooks`, who am I calling?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Yes, that's right on the `Item` method. When you call `Worksheets`, you're accessing the `Worksheets` property of the `Application` class, the global singleton class representing the Excel instance itself. This property happens to be named `Worksheets` (just a property name) and it returns an object of type `Worksheets` (now that's a type name).

Comment: *You answered, I didn't refresh*

Comment: ++ Nicely Explained :)