# VBA Tab creation

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create multiple worksheets in a workbook as per values in coloumn A.
The names of the worksheets should be as per the data in coumn A.

I have created a vba code for the same but I am not able to loop it after first cell to seond cell and so on. Below is the my code.

```
Sub inputboxandsheetname()

    Dim myValue As Variant

    Dim irow As Long

    irow = 1

    Do While Cells(irow, 1) <> Empty

        myValue = Cells(irow, 1)

        If myValue <> "" Then

            Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

            ActiveSheet.Name = myValue

        End If

        irow = irow + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA Excel macro: use Range to act on a different worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656443/vba-excel-macro-use-range-to-act-on-a-different-worksheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cells(irow, 1) <> Empty`
If you don't qualify the range with a sheet object, it will always refer to the `ActiveSheet`. When you add a new sheet, this becomes the active sheet which will contain blank cells.

Also, `Empty` is used in VBA to check if a variant variable has a value assigned to it, not to check if a range contains a value.

Try the following instead:

```
Sub SO()

Dim indexSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Set indexSheet = ActiveSheet
i = 1

While indexSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value <> vbNullString
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = indexSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
    i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(irow, 1) <> Empty` [is in fact](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20737979/11683) `Cells(irow, 1).Value <> Empty`. `Value` is `Variant`, so it is exactly the case of checking if a variant variable has a value.

Comment: I know that checking in this way _will_ work - but I see a lot of cases where things like `Empty` and `IsEmpty()` are used incorrectly and cause confusion - and so for the case of checking a blank cell I try to advise people against this method unless they understand _why_ and _how_ it works. Just a personal preference.

Comment: Thank you.. It worked fine as per my way. Next time I will make sure to add the points you have mentioned.