# Run-time error '-2147352571(80020005) Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I have `Run-time error '-2147352571(80020005) Type mismatch` in line `.AddItem rs(1)`:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If dbconn.State = adStateClosed Then dbconn.Open strConn

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    ListBox1.Clear
    ListBox1.ColumnCount = 6
    rs.Open "select idClient,client_name,Address,City,state,country from  tblClients ", dbconn

    Do While rs.EOF = False
        i = i + 1
        With UserForm2.ListBox1
            .AddItem rs(1) '---------> getting ERROR HERE PLEASE LET ME KNOW
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = rs(2)
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = rs(3)
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = rs(4)
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = rs(5)
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = rs(0)
        End With
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close

    With cmbCountry
        .AddItem "United States"
        .AddItem "Canada"
        .AddItem "Germany"
        .AddItem "Australia"
    End With
    cmbCountry.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know VB , but may be your datatype is int, but your Listbox.Text type is string, and you get error.

Comment: I am almost certain that this is due to `client_name` being `Null`. `ListBox` does that when you try to add a `Null`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start the debugger when the error occurs. Then in the Immediate Window write `? rs(1)`. If this throws an error, then the rs(1) part is faulty, otherwise the problem is with the `.AddItem`.

In the first case, watch rs in a Watch Window, and determine what properties it has. Maybe it does not have a default property by which you can access the first of something as you try with `rs(1)`. I suppose you are interested in one of the fields, so I would try ? `rs.Fields(1)`.

In the second case rs(1) returns something that is not convertible to string. You may try `? CStr(rs(1))` to see whether it can be converted or watch it in the Watch window. But how you continue from there depends on what you find.

Comment: `rs` is `ADODB.Recordset`. It always has a default property, `Fields`, with the default property `Item` that returns a `Field`, and `Field` has a default property, `Value`, so `rs(1)` is always `rs.Fields.Item(1).Value` [when used without `Set`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200523/11683).

Answer (score -1):

You don't show the database schema, but from looking at the SQL it seems that the first field is numberic (`idClient`) and you are trying to use this with `ListBox.AddItem`, which expects a string.

So, you just have to convert as follows:

```
With UserForm2.ListBox1
    .AddItem Str(rs(1))

    ' etc. ....

End With
```

Comment: hi this is Usman i have used this but it still showing an Run time error ' 13'  type mismatched

Comment: Implicit conversions between numbers and strings is something VB does a lot. It could have not been the problem. Besides, `rs(1)` is the *second* field, `client_name`.