# When should one use ".Value"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginner with Visual Basic, and mainly use it to edit MS Excel files. 
When copying/pasting (Cell) content or other values, in some cases `.value` is added.

When should this be added?

When not?

Is it necessary?

Could it harm my code if I use it in places where it isn't needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recordset .value property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200428/recordset-value-property)

Comment: You have Text, Value and Value2, text is whats in the cell displayed (Formatted for ex), Value and Value2 are the underlying values, eg. difference between .135 and .134590953

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2 or this https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/

Comment: For example I'm having one drop down list in cell C5 from "Sheet1", (this can be used to select names of operators from the sheet). When the macro is started (after selceting a name) I'd like to copy the name that was selected in the dropdownlist to, lets say, "Sheet2". Currently it turns out to paste "Oke" in the cell  "B12" in "Sheet2" (but you now can click on cell B12 and select one of the names.

I'd like the code to (when I've for example selected my own name "Cornelis) to paste Cornelis in B12, preferably without the option using B12 as dropdownlist as well
Does this has the same cause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Excel VBA a `Range` object is a fairly rich thing which corresponds to either a cell or a range of cells. As such it has all sorts of properties (it is in a given row, accessible via the `.Row` property, it has interior color, possible borderlines, formulas, etc. -- all accessible via the right properties after the dot.) `Value` is one of these properties. It refers to the value in the cell -- typically a number or a text. It wouldn't be used when using `Copy` and `Paste` since those methods are used on whole `Range` object -- as can been seen by the fact that they are able to copy formatting and not just raw values.

You can *assign* the value in one cell to another. Even though this looks like copy/pasting it really is quite different and is in some sense a low-tech solution when all you want to do is transfer the values. It can be done using either e.g. `Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value` or `Range("A1") = Range("B1")`. The reason the later works is that `Value` is the *default property* of a `Range` object -- hence `.Value` is implicit in any context in which you aren't treating the `Range` as an actual object.

Personally, I always explicitly use `Value` when I want to either read or set the value in a cell (or range of cells) even though I *could* rely on the fact that `Value` is the default property. Most Excel VBA code makes heavy use of both Range objects and the values in the Range objects. For reasons of readability it is a good idea for your code to be explicit about when it is using the range vs. when it is using the value. If you follow the `excel-vba` tag on SO you will see that it is relatively rare for programmers to rely on Range's default property.

Comment: Good answer, but I would urge you to expand this a bit with a clear statement of the difference between value and formatting.

Comment: @Nile The OP is asking about the difference between `.Value` and `<nothing>`, not between `.Value` and `.Text`. This is a very different kind of difference, and the commenters ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917694/when-should-one-use-value#comment55597005_33917694), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917694/when-should-one-use-value#comment55597051_33917694)) are adding to the confusion.

Comment: First of all I realy appreciate the anwser from John Coleman.
(only need to re-read it a second time, due I'm not a native English speaker.) But it allready clearify's a lot.

Difference between .text and .value2 indeed wern't part of my question. Allthough... It's kind of corrolated with my question... probably could learn some of it as well. I'll keep reading some more on stackoverflow!

Thanks to all of you so far!

Comment: @Nile Good idea. I tried to explain a bit more the difference between a range and simply its value.

Comment: "... Value is the default property of a Range object" may be overstating things a scooch subject to the operation.  I never liked that definition since `Set rng = Range("A1")` obviously sets rng to the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), not the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx).

Comment: [This recent post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927736/vba-sort-key-range-query) may be of interest as it demonstrates both ways that either the .Value or Range Object is interpreted on-the-fly depending upon  the ways it is requested. It fails when the Value is returned by the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) but not when the Range Object is returned.