# Sort key range query

Tags: excel, vba

Why does this work:

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 5)).Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

But this doesn't?:

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 5)).Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range(Cells(1,1)), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

Saying the

> Method Range failed

EDIT

The reason for asking is that I would like the sort key to be dynamic, such as:

```
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range(Cells(intRow, intCol))
```

I can't see how this is done.

Comment: because the `Range` by itself does not mean anything in this context. Try changing `Range(Cells(1,1)` to `Selection(Cells(1,1))` in your 2nd line. It's not best practice, but at least you are tying the `Cells` property to an object in this case. Best practice is to always qualify your Ranges, Cells, Sheets, etc.

Comment: Thanks but selection gives a type mismatch. I have added an edit.

Comment: so just use `Key1:=Cells(intRow, intCol)`

Comment: So simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always best to qualify exactly which objects you are working with and work directly with the objects, as opposed to using `Selection` or just `Range`, as it can sometimes lead to unintended consequences or slow your code down.

Try this:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' replace with your sheet name

'assume you wrap this around a loop to move through intRow and intCol _
 or set them in some other fasion
With ws.Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(5,5)

  .Sort Key1:=.Cells(intRow, intCol), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End With
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Cells` call is already returning a Range object, so you should use

```
Selection.Sort Key1:=Cells(1,1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

I think that your confusion is stemming from the fact that passing two Cells parameters to Range is valid, i.e. `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 5))`, but it is not valid to only pass one Cells parameter, i.e. `Range(Cells(1, 1))`

You can see this for yourself with the following snippet

```
Public Sub test()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, 1))
MsgBox rng.Cells.Count

Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1))
MsgBox rng.Cells.Count

End Sub
```

You will get a message saying 3 for the first msgbox call, but you get an exception when trying to set rng the second time.

As to why the second format is not valid, I have no idea. If you find out why the devs built it this way, let us know.

Comment: Thanks. I have added an edit explaining what I trying to do. I should have said that at the start.

Comment: Actually, `Range(Cells(1, 1))` is equivalent to `Range(Cells(1, 1).Value)`, because it invokes the version of Range that takes one parameter and expects a valid *range address*. So if the cell `A1` contained a valid address, such as "G5", `Range(Cells(1, 1))` would designate the cell `G5`.

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks for demystifying!

Answer (score 2):

> The reason for asking is that I would like the sort key to be dynamic ...

At least part of the problem is relying on `.Select` and the subsequent `Selection` as the working area. If your intention is to work with the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) (the 'island' of data origination in A1) then use a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to define the .CurrentRegion and work with it.

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")     `<~~ set the parent worksheet!
    with .Cells(1, 1).CURRRENTREGION         `<~~ set the 'island' of data
        .cells.Sort Key1:=.cells(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
                    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
                    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    end with
end with
```

I'm a little unclear on what you mean by 'dynamic'. The above will use the cell in the top-left of the area defined by .CurrentRegion. If you used `With .Range("D5:H99")` then `.Cells(1)` would refer to D5.

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.