# Conditional guard IF Not (x = Empty) Then

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following

```
Public Sub BreakAllLinks(ByRef aWkBook As Excel.Workbook)
Dim Link As Variant
Dim myLinks As Variant

myLinks = aWkBook.LinkSources(Type:=Excel.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
If Not (myLinks = Empty) Then
    For Each Link In myLinks
        aWkBook.BreakLink Name:=Link, Type:=Excel.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next Link
End If

End Sub  'BreakAllLinks
```

If myLinks is empty then it works well and avoids the `For Each` loop but if myLinks contains some links then I get the following error

> Runtime error '13'

What is wrong with `If Not (myLinks = Empty) Then`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LinkSources` returns either `Empty` or an array.

You cannot compare an array with `Empty` using the equality operator.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821922.aspx) shows you the right way of checking the result - using the `IsEmpty` function.

The function succeeds regardless of the value type stored in your `Variant`.
If e.g. you had a `Nothing` in there, you would get error 91.
Or, if you had an object reference in there, your comparison would try to fetch the [default property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200523/11683) of the stored object and compare that to `Empty`.

Which is why you should never check for `= Empty` really, and only use `IsEmpty`.