# VBA dots from database get loaded into textbox as comma

Tags: excel, userform, decimal-point, vba

I know the Headline sounds odd so I will start off with a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the problem is that the point suddenly changes to a comma when I look up an ID in the UserForm.

Before recalling Infos, I am saving all Information rather straightforward:

```
with ws
    Range("BH" & lastRow).value = Me.payinfoOnTime
    Range("BI" & lastRow).value = Me.payinfo30
    Range("BJ" & lastRow).value = Me.payinfo60
    Range("BK" & lastRow).value = Me.payinfo90
    Range("BL" & lastRow).value = Me.payinfo90more
End with
```

Recalling the respective info for a searched ID is done by:

```
Set FoundRange = ws.Range("D4:D500").Find(What:=Me.SearchSuppNo, LookIn:=xlValues)

With ws
    Me.SEpayinfoontime = FoundRange.Offset(0, 56)
    Me.SEpayinfo30 = FoundRange.Offset(0, 57)
    Me.SEpayinfo60 = FoundRange.Offset(0, 58)
    Me.SEpayinfo90 = FoundRange.Offset(0, 59)
    Me.SEpayinfo90more = FoundRange.Offset(0, 60)
end with
```

The Problem is that later calculations for scores are depending on those textboxes and I constantly get an error, unless I always manually change the commas back to points.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Use a replace function to always replace the , with . ?

Comment: But it get's loaded into the TextBox with a comma and from this TextBox entries are edited and calculations performed. So it would Need to be changed before it is loaded into the TextBox. That I don't know how to do...

Comment: I might be wrong here but this seems like a Regional Format definition. If that's the case, can't you simply change the Decimal separator to be `.` from the control panel?

Comment: It's a regional settings problem. If you know your decimal separator(s), you can simply change it to the preferred separator each time you write/read the text box. btw, you don't use your `with` variables in both examples. In the first you'd have to use `.Range(...` and in the second it's not needed at all.

Comment: I am sorry, which control panel do you mean? The Decimal Separator within Excel is a dot.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct those are snips from two different modules, but thank you. How can I achieve this changing of preferred Separators when I fill a textbox? I apologize but I am still new to VBA

Comment: As Cody G mentioned, just use `Replace` on the string to change `,` into `.`. The excel separator is pretty irrelevant I think. It's more about the systems local settings.

Comment: If you store numbers as numeric data types in the database, it should not concern you how they appear in the user interface. If it does, you are doing something wrong - either storing numbers as strings in the database, or trying to operate on locale-dependent textual representations in a locale-independent fashion or vice versa. If you want to let the user use the Windows settings they selected, which you should, use locale-dependent functions to convert your textboxes' contents to numbers before calculating (e.g. `CDbl`, `CLng` etc) as opposed to locale-independent functions (e.g. `Val`).

Comment: @GSerg Thank you for your extensive reply. I am not working with strings or operating with...whatever you said haha...I am to new to this to even know. I am just working with a UserForm where you can look up Infos belonging to an ID and then edit it when needed. Now, if something is edited, recalculations on other Worksheets are needed. However, if everytime I look up Infos the Point from the worksheet is replaced by a comma, an type mismatch error occurs because it's not a number anymore. Does my explanation make anything clearer? ^^

Comment: Please show the code where "an type mismatch error occurs".

Comment: A Runtime Error 13 "Type Mismatch" occurs at the Point where I want to save a certain score based on what is in the TextBox: `Range("AM" & DatabaseRow).value = Int(Me.SEpayinfoontime) / 10`

Comment: `Int` expects a number. If you give it a string, it will be automatically converted to a number first. Automatic conversion is done with respect to the system locale. If you have a comma in the textbox and automatic conversion fails to convert that, then your system locale decimal dot is not a comma. That means you should look at code that populates textboxes, and check if the system decimal dot is the same as `Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)`.

Comment: I changed it as you said but still got the same error...thank you though! The answer below solved the Problem :)

Comment: How would I check whether the System decimal dot is the same? The populating code is really just `Me.SEtextboxname = FoundRange.Offset(0, number)` for over 200 Textboxes

Comment: In the immediate window, execute `? CStr(42.42)` and `? Str(42.42)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
Me.SEpayinfoontime = FoundRange.Offset(0, 56)
```

[is in fact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200523/11683):

```
Me.SEpayinfoontime.Value = FoundRange.Offset(0, 56).Value
```

When you populate an `MSForms.TextBox` using the `.Value` property (typed `As Variant`), like you implicitly do, and providing a number on the right side, the compiler passes the value to the `TextBox` as a number, and then the value is automatically converted to string inside the `TextBox`.

Exactly how that conversion happens does not appear to be documented, and from experiment, it would appear there is a problem with it.

When you freshly start Excel, it would appear assigning `.Value` will convert the number using the `en-us` locale, even if your system locale is different. But as soon as you go to the Control Panel and change your current locale to something else, `.Value` begins to respect the system locale, and changes its result depending on what is currently selected.

It should not be happening and I would see it as an Excel bug.

---

But if you instead assign the `.Text` property, the number is converted to string using the current system decimal dot, and that conversion happens outside of the `TextBox`, because the compiler knows `.Text` is a string, so it converts the right-hand side number to string beforehand.

So in your situation I would:

- Make sure I always use the `.Text` property explicitly:

  ```
  Me.SEpayinfoontime.Text = ...
  ```
- Make sure I explicitly use the correct kind of functions to convert between text and numbers:

  ```
  Me.SEpayinfoontime.Text = CStr(FoundRange.Offset(0, 56).Value)

  MsgBox CInt(Me.SEpayinfoontime.Text) / 10
  ```

  although this step is optional and represents my personal preference. Given that it's a `string` on the left side of the assignment, VB will use `CStr` automatically.
- Go to Excel's settings to make sure the "Use system separators" tick is set.
- Check what locale is selected in the Control Panel - Language and Regional settings.

  - If it is not `En-Us`, I would select `En-Us` to make sure the decimal separator is a dot there.
- Restart Excel.

Comment: Wow, what an extensive answer again. Would I also Need to Change something to the way I am saving the Input when an ID is first created?
`ws.Range("BH" & lastRow).value = Me.payinfoOnTime`

Comment: Yes, you would: `ws.Range("BH" & lastRow).value = CDbl(Me.payinfoOnTime.Text)`.