# VBA Function - Argument Not Optional

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Function RETURN_Equipment(Optional category As String) As Collection
    Dim config As classConfiguration
    Set config = New classConfiguration

    Dim item As classItem
    Set item = New classItem

    Dim myCollection As Collection
    Set myCollection = New Collection

    For Each config In Configurations
        For Each item In config.colItems
            If IsMissing(category) Then   
                myCollection.add item
            ElseIf InStr(category, "mainframe") <> 0 And item.category = "mainframe" Then
                myCollection.add item
                MsgBox "Fired!"                
            ElseIf category = "accessory" And item.category = "accessory" Then
            Else
            End If
        Next
    Next

    RETURN_Equipment = myCollection
End Function
```

I keep getting

> Compile error:
>   Argument not optional

I get the error on the last line

```
RETURN_Equipment = myCollection
```

I understand the error message, its telling me I did not fill out a parameter. But I only have one parameter, and I've declared it optional. It looks like the code thinks I'm trying to call the function from the function?

What gives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5965593/11683

Comment: The default 'value' of collection is `.Item` which requires an index. To assign the reference of the collection object to a variable you need to use the `Set` keyword at the start of the line.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Anytime you assign an object you need to use the `set` keyword.

`set RETURN_Equipment = myCollection`

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! Now that you've pointed it out it makes complete sense.

Answer (score 9):

I was getting this error because I was using the wrong function name when trying to return a result from a function.  I was doing this:

```
Function MyFuncA(arg as String)
    MyFuncB = arg 'The problem is I'm using MyFuncB instead of MyFuncA
End Function
```

This happened because I copied a function from somewhere else and changed the name, but not the return statement.  This is not the OP's problem, but I was getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've specified the Optional Parameter as a string it will default to an empty string if you've not specified a value.

This means it can't be missing

If you'd specified it as

```
Public Function RETURN_Equipment(Optional category) As Collection
```

It would be a variant and that could be missing, although you'd also be able to mess things up by passing non string variants as the category parameter

The best course of action is probably to replace

```
If IsMissing(category) Then
```

with

```
If category = "" Then
```

And as Brad has pointed out you'll need to use Set

```
Set RETURN_Equipment = myCollection
```

For full details check this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251721%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: I did notice that the IsMissing() wasn't firing, but hadn't looked into it with my assignment error mucking everything up. Thanks for the tip you saved me some grief today. Regards,