# Inserting a VB macro throws Argument not optional error

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, com-interop

I am trying to open a Word document from a C# app, insert a macro, run it, then close. The problem I am running into is

> Compile Error: Argument not optional

I've been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574083/vba-function-argument-not-optional) article but I am not returning anything. Not seeing what I am missing here.

Here is the debugger:

[image]

Here is the C# code:

```cs
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application newApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
newApp.Visible = true;
object Unknown = Type.Missing;
var Source = fileName;
var doc = newApp.Documents.Open(Source);

var project = doc.VBProject;
var module = project.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);

var macro = "Public Sub DoKbTest()\r\n" +
                "MsgBox 'Hello'\r\n" +
            "End Sub\r\n" +
            "Public sub DoKbTestWithParameter(sMsg As String)\r\n" +
                "MsgBox sMsg\r\n" +
            "End Sub";

module.CodeModule.AddFromString(macro);
newApp.Run("DoKbTest");
newApp.Quit(ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
```

Comment: What does VB.NET have to do with this?

Comment: VBA expects strings to be in quotes. Can you try `"MsgBox \"Hello\"\r\n" +` ?

Comment: FYI you don't need to pass `Type.Missing` to every single missing optional parameters in a COM interop call, since .net 4.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single quote in VBA denotes a comment. This is what you're generating:

```vb
Public Sub DoKbTest()
    MsgBox 'Hello'
End Sub
```

Compare to:

```vb
Public Sub DoKbTest()
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

Notice how syntax highlighting looks different with double quotes around the string literal.

You're getting that error because the `MsgBox` function's `Message` parameter isn't optional, and thus the `MsgBox [some comment]` instruction isn't a valid function call.

I'd suggest using a verbatim string, it's much cleaner IMO - simply double-up your double quotes to escape them:

```csharp
    var macro = @"
Public Sub DoKbTest()
    MsgBox ""Hello""
End Sub

Public Sub DoKbTestWithParameter(ByVal msg As String)
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DoubleQuotes to enquote the Text to MsgBox.

```
var macro = "Public Sub DoKbTest()\r\n" +
                    "MsgBox ""Hello""\r\n" +
                 "End Sub\r\n" +
                 "Public sub DoKbTestWithParameter(sMsg As String)\r\n" +
                     "MsgBox sMsg\r\n" +
                 "End Sub";
```

Comment: This is not how you escape quotes in C# in a [non-verbatim literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3311988/11683).

Comment: @GSerg: True - but when I issued the answer the question was flagged not tagged as C# but as VB (changed several times...)

Comment: The code OP showed could not possibly be in VB. Even the single line you quoted cannot be misunderstood as VB because there is no `var` in VB. There wasn't a C# tag initially, but from its [very first edition](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46893953/1) the question explained it's a C# app that generates VBA code.