# Cannot use class object as argument in other class' method

Tags: vba

I'm new to VBA and was surprised it didn't have an official dynamic array, so I tried to make a simple one that suits my needs:

```
    Public count As Integer
    Private max As Integer
    Private storage(1 To 5) As DVprogram

    Private Sub class_initialize()
        count = 0
        max = 5
    End Sub

    Public Sub add(data As DVprogram)
        If (count + 1) > max Then
            updateSize (max + 5)
        End If

        storage(count + 1) = data
        count = count + 1
    End Sub

    'more code...
```

When I try to call add, I get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method."

```
    Dim test As New DVprogram
    Dim temp As New progDynArray
    temp.add (test)
```

When I change the array type to Integers, everything works fine, but when I try to use one of my own classes, it always throws this error. I've tried switching between ByVal and ByRef and neither had any affect. I also found this: [Passing objects to procedures in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965593/passing-objects-to-procedures-in-vba), but the solution there doesn't appear to be my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA Adding a class to a collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331106/vba-adding-a-class-to-a-collection)

Comment: Why not use a Collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Set when assigning objects:

```
 Set storage(count + 1) = data
```

and (as noted by Gopi) you need to drop the `()` when calling your add method:

```
temp.add test
```

You don't use parentheses unless you're calling a function or using the `Call` keyword

**EDIT:** parentheses (without `Call`) don't *always* cause a problem - what they do is cause the argument you're passing to be first *evaluated as an expression*, and the result of that evaluation then get passed.  In the case of `updateSize (max + 5)` that's not a problem, because that's the behavior you want anyway - to add `5` to `max` and pass that value to `updateSize`.  In the case of `temp.add (test)` you *don't* want `test` to be evaluated as an expression.

Comment: Removing the parentheses fixed my issue with the error message, but Add calls an "updateSize" subroutine that calls without issue with parentheses. Why do the parentheses not affect things there but they do elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try temp.add test
instead of temp.add(test)