# Reason for setting variables in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I always had a question regarding setting Collections datatype in VBA

Usual way for Variables, example,

```
Dim userType1 as String
```

But for Collections, we need to declare it as such:

```
Dim userCollection As Collection
Set userCollection = New Collection
```

Why can't you just:

```
Dim userCollection As Collection
```

Why does Collections work differently in VBA?

Never understood this. Need some explanations on this.

**Edit:**

What is the difference between these?

```
userCollection = New Collection
Set userCollection = New Collection
```

Comment: In VB, `Collections` are an _object type_ whereas a `String` (or `Integer`, and several more) are _value types_.  Objects are heap allocated and have to be initialised before use, hence the use of `Set xyz = New abc`, wheres value types are _typically_ allocated on the stack and can be used without initialisation.

Comment: @MartinParkin that is an answer, not a comment... please write that as an answer...

Comment: And for `Set`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17877644/11683 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5966716/11683.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between dim and set in vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872339/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-and-set-in-vba)

Comment: Not a duplicate since the user didn't know difference about objects and variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's an `Object`

`Dim` (or **Dim**ension) will allocate a certain amount of memory for whichever data type is declared (or a `Variant` if no type is declared) and allow the appropriate IntelliSense menus to become available. This is pretty much the be-all and end-all of `Dim`.

So for an object, you can allocate memory for it by using:

```
Dim x As Collection
```

But this doesn't actually create the required object, this is where `Set` and `New` come in.

```
Set x = New Collection
```

You can actually declare like so:

```
Dim x As New Collection
```

Which will allow the variable to [auto-instantiate when it is accessed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8114684/11683)<sup>†</sup>

So for example:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim x As Collection
    x.Add "Test" '// <~~ Error, because the actual Collection object doesn't exist yet.

    Set x = New Collection '// <~~ Create a 'New' collection object and 'Set' it's
                           '//     reference to the memory allocated for 'x'

    x.Add "Test 1"         '// <~~ Works fine.

    Dim y As New Collection       
    y.Add "Test 2"         '// <~~ Works fine, because the Collection
                           '//     object will now instantiate itself

End Sub
```

---

<sup>†</sup>*Credit to [GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg) for clarifying the auto-instantiate feature as I initially got this wrong...*

---

Comment: Declaring `As New` in VBA is not declare+initialize. The variable is still `Nothing` after the Dim executes. But it will now [auto-instantiate whenever it is accessed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8114684/11683) but is Nothing.

Comment: Good spot - took my eye of the locals window for a sec there :) I'll update my answer.